# How can I Debug.Draw different shapes in unity?

Tags: unity, debugging

I want draw new shapes in Sence for example I want `Debug.DrawSphere` can I Debug.DrawCollider?
Is possible that I Debug.DrawSphereCast

Comment: i find DebugX but I don't know how can i use it http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/DebugX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use unity's Gizmos to draw cubes and spheres. [Script Reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.html).

```
void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawSphere(this.transform.position, 1);
}
```

Comment: @nights For drawing shapes in the build, you could use [ALINE](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/aline-162772).